# RegExp Negative Lookahead In JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a RegExp that will match all subdomains of a site ASIDE from one.  I think that the best way to do this is with a lookahead, and I think I'm pretty close.

I will use amazon.com as an example.  test.amazon.com will be the subdomain I want to avoid.

So far I've got this:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("https?://(?!test\.)([^/]+\.)?amazon\.com/.*")
```

However, it seems that the (?!test.) will break ANY subdomain that *begins* with "test".  My hope was that the `\.` would force the RegExp to only fail if there was a period directly following "test".  This doesn't seem to be the case.

```
var regexp = new RegExp("https?://(?!test\.)([^/]+\.)?amazon\.com/.*")

regexp.test("https://amazon.com/")
true //Passes Correctly

regexp.test("https://www.amazon.com/")
true //Passes Correctly

regexp.test("https://atest.amazon.com/")
true //Passes Correctly

regexp.test("https://test.amazon.com/")
false //Fails Correctly

regexp.test("https://tester.amazon.com/")
false //Fails Incorrectly
```

Comment: In double quotes, use `"\\"` if you mean `"\"`. Slash is removed when a string literal is interpreted, so RegExp gets plain `"."` for your `"\."`. It would get (correct) `"\."` for your `"\\."`, which would solve the problem (I'm unsure if it's idiomatic js; maybe some other form of string/regexp literal should be preferred instead).

Comment: @AntonKovalenko is correct, your code works if you fix your slashes to this: var regexp = new RegExp("https?://(?!test\\.)([^/]+\\.)?amazon\\.com/.*")

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/eteTz/1/ for a working example.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like `https?://(?!test)([^.]+\\.)?amazon\\.com/`

Comment: that did it!  If one of you submits an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206004/hwnd) posted the correct answer:

```
https?://(?!test)([^.]+\\.)?amazon\\.com/
```